# Using two tenses in the same sentence

Tags: grammar, tense, tense-agreement

While reporting a past even as a reason for the current action, should I use past tense or present tense?

For example,

> "The parents curse the young man who eloped with their daughter"

Is this sentence correct?

I am confused if I should use "has eloped" in the the place of "eloped"

> "The parents curse the young man who has eloped with their daughter"

I couldn't use google effectively to find the right answers.

Comment: Why do you use "curse" instead of a past tense "cursed"?  In  context what do you mean by "curse" - a literal magical hex, or a figurative "speak ill of".

Comment: In general you should use the right tense for each clause, and those tenses might be the same or they might be different. See other similar questions: there are plenty of questions about using two different tenses in the same sentnce

Comment: Both your options are possible. The first is more neutral. The second (assuming this is narrative) has the function of creating a temporal focus at the time they are cursing, and so may draw the reader inside the narrative more.

Comment: Didn't the daughter take an equal part in, and responsibility for, the elopement?

Comment: @ColinFine It is a narrative. A context is described here. So, I assume it is okay to use "has eloped" in this situation. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is OK, and, as I say, it invites the reader to be "travelling along the story" with the parents, rather than reading it from outside.

Comment: _Has eloped_ suggests that the elopement is recent. You could use the simple past even if it happened years ago (and they are still angry about it!).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey are you suggesting that parents are objective and rational about their children?

Comment: @JamesK - my parents curse the day they bought a Ford.

Comment: @barbecue - just because we are capable of, and even accustomed to, being stupid, that doesn't mean we have to be.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Emotional attachment people stupid. It's human nature.

Comment: @barbecue - blaming the boy only when the girl was willing to elope is sexist.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You MIGHT be able to make a case for that IF you could demonstrate that those same parents did not have the same reaction for their male child when he eloped with someone. But since we're talking about a hypothetical example, I prefer not to make unwarranted assumptions and assign malicious intent to imaginary people.

Comment: To clarify my position, and hopefully fend off a bunch of unnecessary drama, I am in no way saying that sexism does not exist. I'm not saying that men don't get away with things that women do, or vice versa. I'm not saying ANYTHING AT ALL about gender-specific intentions or motives. I'm simply saying that if you made a gender neutral version of the original example, it would still make perfect sense, because parents (regardless of gender) tend to favor their children over outsiders (regardless of gender.) If you dispute this, feel free to say so, but I think it's a pretty far-fetched notion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one sentence you can describe a present, past, or future feeling about a past, present or future thing:

The parents curse the young man who eloped with their daughter

The parents will curse the young man who is eloping with their daughter

The parents have not met the young man who will elope with their daughter

(etc)

Comment: The parents have not met the young man who had eloped with their daughter
The parents have not met the young man who has eloped with their daughter
The parents curse the young man who might elope with their daughter

So, can we say all the above are grammatically correct?

Comment: @Ammu - yes, they are all grammatical.